# Single or multiple layouts?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to both android and java but have been taking some beginner courses on Udacity and reading tutorials. I am looking to create an questionnaire app with about 15 questions total. One question per page, changes when next button clicked. The questions will have different content and number of answers. I know how to create radiogroups and Radiobuttons. Is it stupid to create an activity/layout for each question? I've invested many hours reading and trying to find ways to do this by using only 1 layout with no luck.

Thanks in advance!
Chris

Comment: too broad 
There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks, I've shortened and re-worded my question to focus on my current main challenge. I am only a few weeks into android and this is my first time on here so I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Even with the edit it would be helpful to narrow this down to a specific question. Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: Thanks, I had changed the content but not the Title, changed the title also now.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `ViewPager`.

Read about `Fragments & ViewPager` here:
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

If content of different `Activities` or `Fragments` is equal in terms of layout, or almost equal, the DRY principle applies (Don't repeat yourself), never copy paste layouts just do have different .xml files.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll spend a couple days reading about these and trying them out.